# Magento 1.9 cart not working in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I have a fresh install of `Magento 1.9` from the `Bitnami` stack.  Adding a product to the cart doesn't work in any version of `IE`, even 10 and 11. After clicking the `Add to cart` button it goes to the cart page but it the cart is empty.  No errors are being shown in the `JS` console.  Using `FF` works.  Has anyone come across this with `IE` and `Magento 1.9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the base url in `System->Configuration->Web` from `localhost` to my local `IP` address and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because cookies are not getting set when you are using the IE.
AS IE and chrome does not treat the *localhost* as a valid domain.

When you use IP address that is treated as valid domain and cookies are set.